# normalize all data to single gene (observation) in r

Tags: r, normalization, plyr

I have some protein expression data from 850 proteins and I would like to normalize the data to a reference protein. It is a good way to correct for technical errors. I am new to R and just figured out to make a tidy dataset. But when I search for normalization- it is mostly scaling the data. I can not find good ways to ratio to a data point in the data set. So I have the following, where type=D or T, pt.num=1-8, and there are 859 GeneIDs with 9952 elements in 612.9 kb file.

```
> head(df10g)
  GeneID type pt.num   value
1    A2M    D      1  8876.5
2   ABL1    D      1  2120.8
3   ACP1    D      1  1266.6
4   ACP5    D      1 67797.6
5 ACVRL1    D      1   650.1
6   ACY1    D      1  6264.8
318 IGF2R    D      1   6294.8
```

I would like to normalize to IGF2R for each pt.num.type. But I can't quite figure out the semantics on it. I want this type of function

```
Norm.ig2Fr=GeneID.type.pt.num(value)/IG2FR.type.pt.num(value)

Norm.ig2fr=ASM.D.1 (value)/IG2FR.D.1 (value)

Norm.ig2fr=8876.5/6294.8
```

The desired output would be

```
GeneID type pt.num   value              Norm.ig2fr      log2Norm.ig2fr
    1    A2M    D      1  8876.5        1.41            0.49
    2   ABL1    D      1  2120.8
    3   ACP1    D      1  1266.6
    4   ACP5    D      1 67797.6
```

I think I can use either a mutate or ddply transform but I am missing something to fix the denominator of the ratio to the same GeneID value but varying the pt.num and type.

```
df11 <- ddply(df10g, .(pt.num), transform, Norm.ig2b=value/IGF2R)
```

or

```
df10.igf2r<- mutate(df10t, .(type, pt.num), Norm.ig2fr=value/IG2FR)

dput(df10g)
structure(list(GeneID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("A2M", 
"ABL1", "ACP1", "ACP5", "Activated Protein C", "ACVRL1", "ACY1"),class = "factor"), type = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D"), pt.num = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), value = c(8876.5, 
2120.8, 1266.6, 67797.6, 650.1, 6264.8)), .Names = c("GeneID", 
"type", "pt.num", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any suggestions or insight would be appreciated. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably what you meant. I could not come up with a solution with `plyr`. But, I would like to make a suggestion with `dplyr`. I created a sample data here to demonstrate the code. I think you want to group `type` and `pt.num` using `group_by()`. Then, you want to do the normalisation in `mutate()`. `value[GeneID == "IGF2R"]` specifies the value for `IGF2R` in each group. For instance, for the group of D-1, `value[GeneID == "IGF2R"]` is 1281.000, and for the group of T-1, `value[GeneID == "IGF2R"]` is 1561.364. Using these values, R does the normalisation for each group.

```
set.seed(111)
mydf <- data.frame(GeneID = rep(c("A2M", "ABL1", "ACP1", "ACP5",
                                  "ACVRL1", "ACY1", "IGF2R"), times = 2),
                   type = rep(c("D", "T"), each = 7),
                   pt.num = 1,
                   value = runif(14, 1200, 8800),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#   GeneID type pt.num    value
#1     A2M    D      1 5706.658
#2    ABL1    D      1 6721.257
#3    ACP1    D      1 4015.207
#4    ACP5    D      1 5113.421
#5  ACVRL1    D      1 4070.240
#6    ACY1    D      1 4379.364
#7   IGF2R    D      1 1281.000
#8     A2M    T      1 5245.444
#9    ABL1    T      1 4484.421
#10   ACP1    T      1 1911.980
#11   ACP5    T      1 5423.927
#12 ACVRL1    T      1 5685.737
#13   ACY1    T      1 1710.273
#14  IGF2R    T      1 1561.364

library(dplyr)             
group_by(mydf, type, pt.num) %>%
mutate(out = value / value[GeneID == "IGF2R"])


#   GeneID type pt.num    value      out
#1     A2M    D      1 5706.658 4.454847
#2    ABL1    D      1 6721.257 5.246884
#3    ACP1    D      1 4015.207 3.134433
#4    ACP5    D      1 5113.421 3.991743
#5  ACVRL1    D      1 4070.240 3.177394
#6    ACY1    D      1 4379.364 3.418708
#7   IGF2R    D      1 1281.000 1.000000
#8     A2M    T      1 5245.444 3.359527
#9    ABL1    T      1 4484.421 2.872118
#10   ACP1    T      1 1911.980 1.224557
#11   ACP5    T      1 5423.927 3.473840
#12 ACVRL1    T      1 5685.737 3.641520
#13   ACY1    T      1 1710.273 1.095371
#14  IGF2R    T      1 1561.364 1.000000
```

Applying the same procedure in `data.table`, the following code is also working.

```
library(data.table)
foo <- setDT(mydf)[, out := value / value[GeneID == "IGF2R"], by = list(type, pt.num)]
print(foo)

 #   GeneID type pt.num    value      out
 #1:    A2M    D      1 5706.658 4.454847
 #2:   ABL1    D      1 6721.257 5.246884
 #3:   ACP1    D      1 4015.207 3.134433
 #4:   ACP5    D      1 5113.421 3.991743
 #5: ACVRL1    D      1 4070.240 3.177394
 #6:   ACY1    D      1 4379.364 3.418708
 #7:  IGF2R    D      1 1281.000 1.000000
 #8:    A2M    T      1 5245.444 3.359527
 #9:   ABL1    T      1 4484.421 2.872118
#10:   ACP1    T      1 1911.980 1.224557
#11:   ACP5    T      1 5423.927 3.473840
#12: ACVRL1    T      1 5685.737 3.641520
#13:   ACY1    T      1 1710.273 1.095371
#14:  IGF2R    T      1 1561.364 1.000000
```

Comment: This solution is great. Does just what I was looking for. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @New_to_R Pleasure. I am glad to hear that this helped you. :)